# Dynamic "AddAuthentication()" credentials in .Net Core possible?

Tags: authentication, .net-core, single-sign-on

I am using .AddFacebook() extension method in my Startup class. In here I set the AppId and AppSecret.

Is there any way to set these options depending on the current web request instead?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to solve the underlying problem is to specify each credentials as a separate provider.

Example:

```
.AddFacebook("My Facebook Provider", facebookOpts => {
     facebookOpts.AppId = myAppId;
     facebookOpts.AppSecret = myAppSecret;
     facebookOpts.CallbackPath = "signin-facebook-myFacebookProvider";
 });
```

It's important to override the CallbackPath! If you have multiple calls to .AddFacebook, they will all try to hit the same callback path and you will get a server error.